# Find the interval(s) in which function is dercreasing.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, inequality

For what values (or intervals) of 'a' it holds $a(a-1)x^{a-2}(x-2)+2a(x+1)^{a-1}<0$, where $x\ge2$.

I tried to do it by first derivative test but it again gives almost same type expression which is difficult to solve.

For $a=\frac{-1}{2}$ it becomes $\frac{3}{4}(x-2)x^{\frac{-5}{2}}-(x+1)^{\frac{-3}{2}}<0$.

Comment: Can you give a bit more background on where you got this? The answer I get is not expressible in simple terms: if $w \log w = 4 \log \frac32$, then $a \in \left(\dfrac{w}{\log 2 - \log 3}, 0 \right)$ for that inequality to hold $\forall x \ge 2$.

Comment: @Macavity
For integer $c\ge1$, the function $f(x)=(x-c)(x+2)^{-1/2}+(2c-x)(x+1)^{-1/2}-(c-1)x^{-1/2}$ decreasing for $x\ge c+1$.
I want to replace power -1/2 to some general interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint:

it is trivial that when $a>1$, LHS $>0$, so we can see $a<1$

if $1>a>0$, prove LHS $>0$

then $a<0,$ let $t=-(a-1) >1 $

we need to find $-tx^{-t-1}(x-2)+2(x+1)^{-t}>0 \iff 2>t(1-\dfrac{2}{x})(1+\dfrac{1}{x})^t =f(t)$

$f(t)$ is mono increasing function, the rest you should be OK.